# Click right to "Go to source code" with Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search

I am using Texstudio (2.10.4). A great and useful function of the integrated visualizer is that if I right click at some point of the pdf, I can go to the corresponding code. This worked well in the previous versions of Texstudio. Now, when I click right the visualizer goes to the next page and the "go to source code" becomes less useful!

Any idea how I can fix this ?

**Update**: I got an answer from one of the TeXstudio's developer. I add my reply.

> I am not aware that anything was changed concerning the right click in
>   the pdf viewer.

This problem is probably not related to the update of TeXstudio but to my new computer and its configuration. However, it seems that I am not the only one to experience this issue.

> Apart from that **ctrl+left click** should jump to source directly.

A useful recommendation. Unfortunately it does not work for me. left click or ctrl+left click jumps me to the next page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also had this bug recently. The bug is not related with the actual application; it is due to corrupted profile. This is what I learned after some experimentation. So, for the Mac OS, look at your home directory--> there is  a hidden **Config** folder there. There is *Texstudio* folder inside the **config** folder. Close Textstudio and remove   the **Texstudio.ini** (the profile file) file in the folder.  Texstudio will recreate the file when you restart it. This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 6):

New answer inspired by @Dellu: you need to restore the default settings to fix this problem. Just **delete the settings file** (texstudio.ini), while Texstudio is not running. Otherwise it will recreate the file with the present settings on closing. Note: If you only want to restore the default settings temporarily, rename texstudio.ini (e.g. texstudio-backup.ini).

Update that might be helpful for other users: I upgraded to TeXstudio 2.12.16. Then, while I was in the editor I used the "go to PDF" command, nothing happened. Moreover, I right-clicked on the PDF, there was no option "go to source". I solved this issue again by deleting the default settings (texstudio.ini, which is on C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\texstudio in Windows 7), while Texstudio is not running.

Old answer: Let me post a simple trick: left click in the pdf viewer goes one page down, then right click goes one page up and the "go to source code" opens!

Comment: old is gold for me;-)

Comment: @emeryville: The old answer seems to be the best one.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, which turns out to be a bug. It worked for me to just press the icon picturing a hand on top of the in-line viewer (it was currently toggled to the magnifying glass). I imagine simply restarting the editor may have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the feature is still working on smaller documents. If it does, the problem is in the length of the file, as apparently it does not work on "too long" .tex files.

To solve it you can split it in two external files .tex and import them with \import in a main file.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the PDF or the source code within Texstudio, go to options in the ribbon, left click and choose "Restore default settings" then you would be able to go to the code source or move to PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution was to delete the package cache which is located in the folder `$HOME/.config/texstudio`.

Stop Texstudio, delete the file `packageCache.dat`, restart Texstudio.

After this, both *Go to PDF* and *Go to source* worked instantly again, even no build of the document was necessary.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this problem was introduced by using

```
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
```

Apparently other libraries cause similar effects as well - see for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346215/todonotes-interferes-with-ctrl-left-click-in-texmaker).

Side note: In this case while working with the document one can use \newpage to circumvent the problem.