# `todonotes` interferes with `ctrl` + `left click` in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, todonotes

I am using `Texmaker`. I really like the feature where you `ctrl` + `left click` in the pdf, and then the editor jumps to that location. I have found that the `shadow` option in the `todonotes` package interferes with this when I `ctrl` + `left click` on the first page it always jumps to `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` instead.

**Minimal example**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, obeyFinal, shadow]{todonotes} %todo notes

\begin{document}
clicking here jumps to pgflibraryfadings.code.tex
\newpage
clicking here jumps to the correct place
\end{document}
```

Removing the `shadow` option fixes the `ctrl` + `left click` behavior, but I would like be able to use both. Any suggestions as to how I can do so?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with texstudio but not with sumatra. Loading `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` or adding a `
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading` to a document disturbs the synching. Imho you should make a bug report at the site of the editor.

Comment: Are there any news here?