# How does the cursor go to the place of a certain word in a text file when it clicked in a pdf file?

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search

I use teXstudio as an editor to write my manuscript. For building PDF files, I exploit SumatraPDF v3.1.2 64bit. Once I compile my file, it opens in sumatra as a pdf file. But when I click on a certain word in the opened pdf file, the cursor is shown at the beginning of the paragraph in the text file (had been opened in teXstudio) instead of being at the right place of the that certain word. How can I change the program's options to show the cursor in the right place of a word in the text file when I click on that in the SumatraPDF?

Comment: That's probably a question for Benito van der Zander or the people over at SumatraPDF.

Comment: I think SyncTeX only knows about line numbers, so this may not be possible. You can get better precision by starting every sentence on a new line (but giving every word a line of its own might make your TeX file hard to read).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TeXstudio "go to source" inaccuracy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429309/texstudio-go-to-source-inaccuracy)

Comment: @thymaro certainly not a SumatraPDF issue per see as it only responds to the data its given and responds with the corresponding line number. There is a possibility that TeXstudio could be updated to be more precise in breaking apart the index of TeX blocks recorded in the synctex file but  part of the issue is how synctex traditionally stored that info and "fudging" may not the way to go since you cant please all the users all the time. Certainly some editors are better than others at two way sync but they usually have a dedicated integrated viewer.